# SortedSet or any Collection and then Collections.sort()?

Tags: sorting

I need a collection of elements. I only will add new elements and iterate over all the collection. And I need that elements are sorted. But I don't need arbitrary access, only those two operations.

What is better (more efficient), use a SortedSet (every added element will be sorted) or use a Collection (e.g. List) and after the last insertion sort that (Collections.sort)?

Remember that the iteration must return sorted elements.

Thanks!

Comment: use a Collection (e.g. List) and after the last insertion sort that (Collections.sort) would be best option performance wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Collections.sort` have time complexity of nlog(n) and same is with `TreeSet`. The difference is `TreeSet` have an overhead of sorting all the elements with each insert and remove. Hence if you want to iterate over sorted collection after adding all the elements then better to use `Collections.sort`.
This also allows you to use linked list which allows duplicate elements if need be.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically both methods have the same complexity :

Inserting `n` elements and then sort the list

```
n * O(1) + O(n log(n)) = O(n log(n))
```

Inserting `n` elements in a sortedList

```
n * O(log(n)) = O(n log(n))
```